# Reading excel file into array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read an excel file and create a multidimensional array in javascript with it.
The excel file will look like:

```
AA11 AA22 AN65
AB11 AB22 AN64
...
```

I need it to create an array that looks like:

```
[
    [AA11, AA22, AN65],
    [AB11, AB22, AN64]
]
```

So far, I've been able to bring up a file selection window, and I believe it's reading the file, I just think it might not be putting the data into the array correctly. This is what I have so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#input").on("change", function () {
            var excelFile,
            var array = [[],[]];
                fileReader = new FileReader();

            $("#result").hide();

            fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                var buffer = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);

                $.ig.excel.Workbook.load(buffer, function (workbook) {
                    var column, row, newRow, cellValue, columnIndex, i,
                        worksheet = workbook.worksheets(0),
                        columnsNumber = 0,
                        gridColumns = [],
                        data = [],
                        worksheetRowsCount;
                    while (worksheet.rows(0).getCellValue(columnsNumber)) {
                        columnsNumber++;
                    }
                    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                        column = worksheet.rows(0).getCellText(columnIndex);
                        gridColumns.push({ headerText: column, key: column });
                    }
                    for (i = 1, worksheetRowsCount = worksheet.rows().count() ; i < worksheetRowsCount; i++) {
                        newRow = {};
                        row = worksheet.rows(i);

                        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                            cellValue = row.getCellText(columnIndex);
                            //newRow[gridColumns[columnIndex].key] = cellValue;
                            array[row,columnIndex] = cellValue;
                        }

                        window.alert(array[0][0]);
                        data.push(array);
                    }

    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "excel file" do you mean `.xls / .xlsx` or is it a `.csv` file?

Comment: It appears as though you're using some kind of third-party library to help you with reading the workbook. You may want to [edit] your question to include the name of that library in the question (and in the tags, if it exists).

Comment: Oneliner `let input = "A B C
DD EE FF"; // tab seperated \t

let clean = input.replace(/^/g, '["').replace(/\t/g, '","').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '"], ["').replace(/, \[$/, '');
clean = clean.substring(0, clean.length-4);
let arr = JSON.parse('['+clean+']')`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure what you're using to parse the Excel, is it [IgniteUI](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui/frameworks/excel-library) ? For what it's worth, the free (community edition) of SheetJS, [js-xlsx](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx) provides a few functions that produce exactly the output you needed, given the spreadsheet you provided.

The docs are a bit messy, but they are complete, the most interesting sections for this use-case are: *Browser file upload form element* under [Parsing workbooks](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks) and [XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx#json). You can run a test with the type of spreadsheet you provided in the code sample below:

```js
$("#input").on("change", function (e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   // input canceled, return
   if (!file) return;
   
   var FR = new FileReader();
   FR.onload = function(e) {
     var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
     var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});
     var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
     
     // header: 1 instructs xlsx to create an 'array of arrays'
     var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet, { header: 1 });
     
     // data preview
     var output = document.getElementById('result');
     output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
   };
   FR.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="input" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods">
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Which lines of code in this are writing the array to the document? I'm trying to get it to just store the array as a variable a, but I can't figure out how to have it not write to the document.

Comment: @PreronaKundu, what do you mean, "to the document"? The lines under the comment `// data preview` write the JSON output of the variable `result` (in which the xlsx data is stored) to the <pre> tag. If you want to re-export it in xlsx, you can. Search for `xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet` in the xlsx-js docs.

Comment: instead of writing the JSON output to the <pre> tag, I want to simply store the array data in a variable labeled a, so that I can continue to use this data in another function.

Comment: Well, you can. In the code above it's called `result` but you can label it `a`...

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to print out the <pre> tag to the page. I don't want to visually see the array, I just want to store it in a variable. Is there a way to do this without the <pre> tag or have the tag not appear on the document?

Comment: It looks like JSON.stringify is creating an undefined element that reads the "array" as a text string. I attempted to convert this to a JSON array with no luck. Is there a way to convert this to an actual multidimensional array so that I can index it?

Comment: @PreronaKundu I'm sorry but your last comment makes no sense. Please look at the code inside the `onload` function, add a `console.log(result)`, and re-read my previous comments. The answer is right in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Here the full solution aditionally I've added a group by category function
to demostrante that we can apply functions to the json array.

```js
(async() => {
  const url = "./yourfile.xlsx";
  const data = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer();
  /* data is an ArrayBuffer */
  const workbook = XLSX.read(data);

  const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
  const sheetValues = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

  const groupByCategory = sheetValues.reduce((group, product) => {
  const { category } = product;
  group[category] = group[category] ?? [];
  group[category].push(product);
  return group;
  }, {});

  console.log(groupByCategory)
  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
})();
```