# How upload data from an excel file to an array using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I trying create button in page and with (kind OpenFileDialog ) select file excel. Parse this file.
Find my question, but dont work.
[Reading excel file into array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467704/reading-excel-file-into-array-using-javascript)

```js
$("#fileInput").on("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  // input canceled, return
  if (!file) return;
  var FR = new FileReader();
  FR.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    });
    var firstSheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
    // header: 1 instructs xlsx to create an 'array of arrays'
    var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheet, {
      header: 1
    });
    // data preview
    var output = document.getElementById('result');
    output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
  };
  FR.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" value="Choose Files!" accept=".xls, .xlsx" />
<!--расширение файла -->
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object inherits the [arrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method from [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), the following works (you just need to adapt it to jQuery a bit):

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" value="Choose Files!" accept=".xls, .xlsx" />

<pre id="result"></pre>

<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.18.12/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

```
const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector)

const input = $('#fileInput')

input.addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0]

  if (!file) return

  const data = await file.arrayBuffer()

  const wb = XLSX.read(data)
  const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]]
  const result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
    header: 1
  })

  $('#result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
})
```

Preview: 
[image: preview]

Demo in [codi.link](https://codi.link/PGlucHV0IHR5cGU9ImZpbGUiIGlkPSJmaWxlSW5wdXQiIHZhbHVlPSJDaG9vc2UgRmlsZXMhIiBhY2NlcHQ9Ii54bHMsIC54bHN4IiAvPg0KDQo8cHJlIGlkPSJyZXN1bHQiPjwvcHJlPg0KDQo8c2NyaXB0IGxhbmc9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQiIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uc2hlZXRqcy5jb20veGxzeC0wLjE4LjEyL3BhY2thZ2UvZGlzdC94bHN4LmZ1bGwubWluLmpzIj48L3NjcmlwdD4=%7C%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)

Comment: TY very much! If you don't mind, you can comment on the lines